# Use variable value as Environment parameter in GoCD

Tags: shell, environment-variables, sh, go-cd, pass-by-reference-value

I'm trying to write a shell script which read variables from a file and replace that with the Environment variable define in GoCD.

Now the challenge i'm facing is i'm trying to use value of variable as parameter

Below is my script

```
#!/bin/bash 
filename="keyword.txt" 
while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3
do
        f6="Env_var"
        a="$($f6)"
        echo $a
       # echo "$f1" "$f3"
       # sed -i s|$f1|$($f6)|g /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/StormCluster-Deploy-2/"$f3".xml
done < "$filename"
```

Also in GoCD environment variable,i have given
Env_var = 1234

Now here the script  is giving output
$Env_var

Where as i want that $Env_var value i.e 1234 define in GoCD as Environment variable should be the output

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in GoCD, but in wrong parameter expansion. What you should probably do is:

```
a="${!f6}"
```

You can read more about that in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) section.

Comment: this is even not executing,as not even printing the value

Comment: It works for me in bash. Please try it here: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/bash/4.2.42/2DR